# How to make aggragate tables by date levels

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have fact table with Date dimension with levels `Year`, `Quarter` , `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, two measures `[Measure].[kind sum]`, `[Measure].[kind avg]` and aggragate table for every date level. For example i have a some years period and i am need to get a average of days. In this case the query will be like this

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Pc in avg by day] AS AVG({[Some dimension].Children * Descendants([Date].[2013] : [Date].[2016], [Date].[Day])}, [Measures].[Pc in sum])
SELECT {[Measures].[Pc in avg by day]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Some cube]
```

There is a method how to optipize query. I am need to hold a values like `[Pc in avg by day]`, `[Pc in avg by month]`, `[Pc in avg by quarter]` in aggregate table for year level and etc. I think to make this measures in cube, but in this case this measures wil be work only with aggregate table. I think that it is not correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand your question. I think you want to get [Pc in avg by month], [Pc in avg by quarter] same like [Pc in avg by day]. If this is the case adding them as measures to the cube may not be the correct way.

As you said you have an aggregate table for day with measure [Pc in sum], you may add different aggregate tables for month, quarter and year and modify the query as below if you need [Pc in avg by month]

```
    WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Pc in avg by month] AS AVG({[Some dimension].Children * Descendants([Date].[2013] : [Date].[2016], [Date].[Month])}, [Measures].[Pc in sum])
SELECT {[Measures].[Pc in avg by month]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Some cube]
```

Mondrian should intelligent enough to pick correct aggregate table to fulfil the query. In this case monthly aggregate

Comment: I will try this option and tell about result.

Comment: He will use only aggregate for sum measure.

Comment: I think in the cube schema definition you have to specify the aggregate method (sum, avg etc). That might be the cause. If you need both sum and average you might have to add another measure for count and have may have calculated measure for avg with sum/count. But i'm not sure about this option.